# iOS Crash log debug issues

Tags: ios, debugging, crash

I have crash reported as below at line 659 in ViewController.swift. However i wasn't sure is that the issues reported from crash log where i can't set background color. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

```
   Thread 0 name:  main  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001015bca18 0x101588000 + 215576
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001015bca18 0x101588000 + 215576
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001015dc7c8 0x101588000 + 346056
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001015dc5d0 0x101588000 + 345552
4   Test UAT                        0x00000001005a0fe4 ViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (ViewController.swift:659)
5   Test UAT                        0x00000001005a102c @objc ViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (ViewController.swift:0)
6   UIKit                           0x000000019206b924 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1056
7   UIKit                           0x000000019206b4ec -[UIViewController view] + 28
8   UIKit                           0x0000000192071c98 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 76
9   UIKit                           0x000000019206f138 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
10  UIKit                           0x00000001920e168c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
11  UIKit                           0x00000001922edcb8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4068
12  UIKit                           0x00000001922f3808 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1656
13  UIKit                           0x0000000192308104 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3139 + 48
14  UIKit                           0x00000001922f07ec -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
15  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018dd9392c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
16  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018dd93798 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
17  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018dd93b40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c16ab5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c16a4a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c1680a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c0962b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
22  UIKit                           0x00000001920d67b0 -[UIApplication _run] + 608
23  UIKit                           0x00000001920d1534 UIApplicationMain + 208
24  Test UAT                        0x000000010053a780 main (AppDelegate.swift:43)
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018b0795b8 start + 4
```

ViewController.swift line is  659

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: you should post more code here, I don't think this line has any issue`view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black`

Comment: i can't copy all my code here. Do you mean more crash log details? I'm new to debug crash log.

Comment: you mean this line `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black` caused app crash?

Comment: i wasn't sure but the crash log is pointing to ViewController.swift:659. my code at this line is view.background = UIColor.black.

Comment: post your viewController's code here.

Comment: hi, can u see any problem or issues report from the crash log details that i posted. Or there no way to check from crash log which line causing crash.

Comment: i had problem to post all my code here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133847/discussion-between-aircraft-and-kaneyip).

Comment: Same problem here !